# can't install pandas using docker-compose

Tags: python, django, pandas, docker

I don't know if this is docker-related or pandas or me.

I have a docker container for Django that worked perfectly fine, up until the point I needed to add Pandas. I have tried to install via `requirements.txt` as follows:

```
Django>=2.0
 psycopg2
 python-decouple>=3.1
 selenium>=3.7.0
 ipdb==0.10.3
 argon2-cffi>=18.1.0
 django-widget-tweaks>=1.4.1
 pandas==0.22
```

with the `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` command in the Dockerfile. This works for all other python packages I've tried but not for pandas.

Then I tried to run the command from the Dockerfile with different variations of `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-pandas` or `RUN pip install pandas`

No matter the approach, I try to run `docker-compose up` on the Django container and I get `ImportError: no module named pandas`

Would appreciate any insight.

Comment: When you build the image and the `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` executes, do you see any errors in the output?

Comment: thx for comment. i just used `build` command instead of `up` and it works fine. have to mount postgresql to an external volume to save your data though.